React Native IAP "E_UNKNOWN" error for iOS
I am trying to purchasing a subscription on iOS real device
My sandbox account is added as testing account in app store connect
Versions used -
react-native: 0.73.6
react-native-iap: 12.15.1
When clicked on subscribe purchase update listener being requested in which received the purchase object, purchase object does not contains values for AppAccountToken, PurchaseToken,TransactionReasonIOS, VerificationResultIOS hence throwing "E_UNKNOWN" error
Need to receive all the mentioned fields in purchase update listener
